# Creating separate chunk for core-js with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I'm using Webpack in combination with Babel to generate bundles compatible with older environments.
For this I use babel-loader in Webpack 5.
I'm using @babel/preset-env with the following config:

```
"@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": 3,
        "targets": {
          "browsers": [
            "last 2 versions",
            "not ie < 11",
            "not ie_mob > 0"
          ]
        },
}
```

This works fine, only the needed core-js imports are being added to the bundles I'm generating.
What I did notice, is that a lot of the core-js imports are the same in the different bundles I'm generating.
Since on some pages I have multiple bundles being loaded, I'd like to pull out the core-js imports  into a separate bundle, and load that in my HTML.

I adapted my webpack config like this:

```
optimization: {
    usedExports: true,
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](core-js)[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendor',
          chunks: 'all',
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Now the result it that I'm getting a separate bundle containing the core-js imports from all my separate bundles, but there are a lot of duplicates in there (see 'web.url.js' for example).
[image: My vendor bundle]
How could I configure this so these core-js modules are not duplicated in the vendor bundle?

Comment: Do you have a reproducible repo?

Comment: Hi @tmhao2005, I can't share the code I'm working on since it's under NDA. I think I posted the most important code in the question above, but if you would need any more code let me know and I can share some more!

Comment: @ThomasL: Did you solve it!?